# MySQL Decimal format

Tags: mysql, format, decimal

I have 2 TEXT columns in my table (AmountPaid and AmountRemaining). The format is € 10.000,00

I am trying to create a query that pluses these 2 values, and convert it back to the format as show above (€ 10.000,00). Of course this should also work with for example € 100.000.000,00, € 690,00 or € 10,00 etc...

For now I have this query witch plusses the values:

```
SELECT AmountRemaining, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(AmountRemaining AS CHAR), '€ ', '') , '.', ''), ',00', '') AS DECIMAL) + 
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(AmountPaid AS CHAR), '€ ', '') , '.', ''), ',00', '') AS DECIMAL) FROM Clients
```

The output of this is like this "10000", "13000" etc...

How can I convert this back to the original format?

Thanks.

Comment: Store numeric values as numbers in your table, and do the formatting (adding `€`, changing decimal points to commas and vice versa) when you display them (use [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) with your appropriate locale). Then you won't have these problems.

Comment: @Nick I know that is one way to do it. Please provide an example since it's easier said than done

Comment: I agree with @Nick. This is an artificial problem due to a bad database design.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 TEXT columns in my table.

Wrong.  Text columns contain text.  Use numeric columns for numbers.  That is, cleanse the data on the way in, not on the way out.

Once you have done that, the rest is better done thus:

Use `LOCALE` to establish the desired decimal point and thousands separator.  That is used in the `FORMAT()` function to do the rest of the numeric part.  T tack on the currency symbol, use `CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('€', FORMAT(1234567, 2, 'de_DE'));

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('€', FORMAT(1234567, 2, 'de_DE'))   |
+--------------------------------------------+
| €1.234.567,00                              |
+--------------------------------------------+
```